# Is it possible for kernel mode driver to interact with user at system boot?

Tags: wdk, uefi

I am working on storage filter driver for windows 10 that encrypts the whole drive (similar to Bitlocker software). My driver get loaded at boot time and it need to prompt user for encryption password at power on. Is there a way to do this without making changes to OS loader?

My plan was to use UEFI services to work with display/keyboard, and I tried to find EFI_RUNTIME_SERVICES structure in the kernel memory from my driver, but I didn't find a way to perform memory scan safely.